# I get a 404 error when reloading React Router app

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When I reload my app on a local server, everything is fine. But when I reload the page while hosting on gh-pages, I get a 404 error. It doesn't do this on the home page, but it does on the other 2 pages. Does it have something to do with the fact that it is being hosted remotely? I'm a bit of a noob with React Router. Any help would be appreciated.Here is the relevant code and the link to my app below:

[React Game App](https://envincebal.github.io/react-game-search/)

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Nav />
          <div className="container">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/react-game-search" component={MainPage} />
              <Route path="/games" component={GameSearch} />
              <Route  path="/about" component={About} />}
              <Route  path="/details" component={GamesDetails} />}
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <div className="navbar">
      <div className="navbar-item">
        <NavLink
          exact to="/react-game-search/"
          activeClassName="selected"
          className="nav-link"
        >Home</NavLink>
      </div>
      <div className="navbar-item">
        <NavLink
           to="/games"
          activeClassName="selected"
          className="nav-link"
        >Games</NavLink>
      </div>
      <div className="navbar-item">
        <NavLink
           to="/about"
          activeClassName="selected"
          className="nav-link"
        >About</NavLink>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

class Game extends Component {

  addDefaultSrc = (ev) => {
    ev.target.src = errorIcon;
  }

  render() {
    const { icon, gameTitle, game } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="game-box">
        <Link
          style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}
          to={{
            pathname: "/details",
            state: { game }
          }}>
          <div className="game-content">
            <img className="game-icon" onError={this.addDefaultSrc} src={icon} alt="icon" />

            <p className="game-link"><strong>{gameTitle}</strong></p>

          </div>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because when you reload the page, it tries to access `/games` page for example. But on the github pages, there is only `/` or `/index.html` page. So, you're getting 404 error.

You might find this answer helpful: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1765#issuecomment-285114194

From there:

> Two solutions:
>
> Don’t use HTML5 history on GitHub pages. Use hashHistory instead. Your
>   URLs will look like
>   https://rockchalkwushock.github.io/rcws-development/#path/inside/the/app.
>
> Use process.env.PUBLIC_URL in your route definitions so that they work
>   both in development and after deployment. For example: . This will be empty in
>   development and rcws-development (inferred from homepage) in
>   production.

I would recommend switching to hash navigation policy, so your routes will look like `blabla.com/#game` instead of `blabla.com/game`. It will route all requests to your `index.html`, so you can handle routing using React.

You can read more about using HashRouter in React here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/HashRouter.md

Comment: Thanks. But I'm still confused how to replace the forward slash with the hash symbol on the url. Instead it is placed between the forward slash and the route. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @envincebal sorry, my bad, I've corrected the example. The correct URL is `blabla.com/#game`, so you're doing great.
Please, upvote and accept my answer if it helped you!

Comment: This has a good explanation and approaches. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623117/5111896